# Docker fails to start on Windows 11 with WSL

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I searched on SO for similar questions already, and none of the answers helped.

I installed and uninstalled docker many times and restarted every time. I set the env variable, and I can run docker, and see that it's installed in terminal, but the GUI won't startup.

[image]

This is the error I get when trying to run a hello world command.

```sh
docker: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am running it on a Windows 11 Home version.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have wsl enabled or not?

Comment: How can I enable it? I have WSL 2 installed.

Comment: does your docker desktop GUI load up or not? if not you can check the docker configuration file which should be in your appdata (I don't remember on the top of my head where exactly it is but it should be a quick google search)

Comment: Yeah it loads up but partially. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: did you add yourself to the docker-users group?

Comment: Where can I do that?

Comment: @Arcanus, type *edit local users and groups* into your windows search bar. Under groups you will find one thats called *docker-users*.  You can add your own user there and then restart the machine or maybe sign out and in is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like and issue with the new Docker release. After I downgraded I was able to get it too work. [Docker version 4.4.4](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/#:%7E:text=2022%2D01%2D24-,Download%20Docker%20Desktop,-For%20Windows).

Make sure you allow virtualization too, by running the following command in powershell as Admin: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

Comment: For me the 4.4.4 version doesn't work. I needed a lower version but it keeps auto-updating to this one breaking my local Docker instance

Comment: I believe you can select not to auto-update in Docker settings.